# How to get all the values of a key searching with the value of another key in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with the types of cars that I have on stock:

```
Table cars

idCar  |  name
-------+-------
1      |  car1
2      |  car2
3      |  car3
4      |  car4
```

And another table with the customers that have bought each car:

```
Table sales

idCar  |  idCustomer
-------+------------
2      |  cust1
2      |  cust5
3      |  cust5
3      |  cust2
```

and I have all the values of sales table stored in an array with PHP. It looks like this:

```
array(4) { 
      [0]=> array(2) { 
          ["idCar"]=> string(1) "2" 
          ["idCustomer"]=> string(5) "cust1" 
      } 
      [1]=> array(2) { 
          ["idCar"]=> string(1) "2" 
          ["idCustomer"]=> string(5) "cust5" 
      } 
      .... //Here the rest of values
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the values of a car (or cars) that have been bought by a particular customer, for example, `cust5`.

So, if I search on the sales array for the cars that have bought the customer `cust5` it should return to me, `idCar` with the values `2` and `3`. After I will get the values of `idCar` and `name` with `MySQL` with that values.

I have tried using the following sql statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idCar, $salesTable)";
```

where `$salesTable` is the array that contains the full sales table but of course it does not work because I am trying to parse there an array directly, instead of the values of `idCar`.

I would like only to pass to the sql statement the values of `idCar` that match with a particular customer, in this case, with `cust5`.

Is there some way to get only the values of `idCar` required with some function of PHP giving only `cust5` as parameter so I would be able to apply the sql statement that I put above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do not  you use an `INNER JOIN` in query?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I am going to search now about it. I am relatively new on `MySQL` and I did not notice about it.

Comment: Ok, then read it carefully, to be sure, you understand difference between INNER / LEFT / etc... join.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps undertake a little research before posting.

Comment: @Strawberry As you can see, I am an active user on SO and I know how to ask here. I posted it because I did not find anything searching it before  but it is a bit difficult search something if you do not know that it exists. For sure I was searching in the wrong way.

Comment: I just don't buy it.

Comment: @Strawberry I do not really understand what do you mean with this phrase but I am sorry if it upsets to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `cars`  c
INNER JOIN sales s
ON s.idCar = c.id
AND s.idCustomer = 'cust5'
```